# qunit deepEqual test fails on identical objects

Tags: javascript, qunit

Why does the following test fail?

```
function queryString2Map(queryString) {
    var pairs = [], i, keyValuePair, key, value, map = {};
    if (queryString !== '') {
        pairs = queryString.split('&');
        for (i = 0; i < pairs.length; i += 1) {
            keyValuePair = pairs[i].split('=');
            key = decodeURIComponent(keyValuePair[0]);
            value = (keyValuePair.length > 1) ? decodeURIComponent(keyValuePair[1]) : undefined;
            map[key] = value;
        }
    }
    return map;
}


test("queryString2Map", 1, function () {
    var qs = 'a=123&bob=%20a%20&symbols=%22%24%25%5E%26%3C%3E%2F%5C%3A~%40%3B%23&undef';
    var map = {
        'a': '123',
        'bob': ' a ', 
        'symbols': '"$%^&<>/\\:~@;#',
        'undef': undefined
    };
    deepEqual(queryString2Map(qs), map, "querystring converted to map");
});
```

the object returned by queryString2Map is identical to the map object in the test so why does the test fail?

Comment: I can get this test to pass if I set the constructor of map and the returned object to null so I guess its something to do with the constructors...

Comment: Your code works for me in the latest release versions of Chrome, Firefox and IE9, on WIndows 7. I've using QUnit version 1.9.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try using propEquals, there may be some differences between the parent prototype objects that are not showing up.